# A definition of Stochastic integral that is both a martingale and preserves chain rule?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

my question is straightforward: is there any definition of Stochastic integral (so I assume at least some kind of Riemann sum compatibility and linearity) that is both a local martingale and preserves the chain rule? Or in case this is negative if there's a proven result that there can't be any definition of this kind?

I know that Ito integral preserves the local martingale property, but the chain rule is ``messed up''; then there's Stratonovich definition which preserves chain rule, but the integral is not a local martingale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice question, but I think the answer is no. The integral that preserves ordinary calculus and be a martingale would have to be the Ito and Stratonovich integral at the same time. As we know:
$$
\underbrace{\int_0^tW_s\circ \,dW_s}_{\textstyle \text{Stratonovich}}=\underbrace{\int_0^tW_s\,dW_s}_{\textstyle \text{Ito (Martingale)}}+\frac{t}{2}=\frac{W_t^2}{2}\,.
$$
The last term ensures that the Stratonovich integral follows ordinary calculus. Since $x^2/2$ is convex it is also clear that the Stratonovich integral is a continuous
supermartingale. Therefore:

- The uniqueness of the Doob-Meyer decomposition forbids the existens of another martingale $M_t$ such that the Stratonovich integral would equal $M_t$.

Conversely, if you want an integral that satisfies ordinary calculus, the integral of $W_t$ w.r.t. itself must equal $W^2_t/2$ which is a strict supermartingale and *not* a martingale.

Comment: But this proof assume that the only available definitions are Stratonovich and Ito's (and I think it is implied by the condition of compatibility with the Riemann sums?), isn't it?

Comment: In the last sentence I just added I make no such assumptions. Is that convincing? I know of no stochastic integral w.r.t. BM that is compatible with Riemann sums. That is because in the Riemann integral the point in the partition interval where you evaluate the integrand does not matter whilst in stochastic integration it matters *a lot*.

Comment: Sorry, probably I should've explained what ``compatibility with Riemann sums'' meant. It's the following $\lim_{n\to+\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{p_n-1} B_{t_i}(B_{t_{i+1}\land t} - B_{t_i \land t}) = \int_0^t B_s \, \textrm{d} B_s$ with $t_i$ being a partition of $[0,t]$ whose meshes goes to $0$ (and in a similar manner, if you change $B_{t_i}$ to $(B_{t_i} + B_{t_{i+1}})/2$ you get the same but for Stratonovich's integrals) which is not really the very same thing as Riemann integrals, but it's quite similar. Anyway, now I get the issue far better, thanks a lot!